# MobX computed runs before item is actually inserted into array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobx

I'm using React in combination with MobX. I use a store with an observable array (conversations) and would like to offer a sorted version of this array as a computed property. When adding a new conversation, the computed property sortedConversations is evaluated before the conversation is added to the array. In the small example below, 'Reordering conversations' is always logged before 'Added conversation'. Am I doing something wrong?

```
class Store {

    ...

    @observable conversations = [];

    addConversation(conversation) {
      this.conversations.push(conversation);
      console.log('Added conversation');
    }

    @computed
    get sortedConversations() {
      console.log('Reordering conversations');
      return _.orderBy(this.conversations.slice(), ['lastUpdated'], ['asc']);
    }
}
```

Comment: `Reordering conversations` is logged before `Added conversation` because observers are updated synchronously when observables are changed. Does your component not re-render? Have you decorated it with `@observer`?

Comment: I don't have the answer, but I noticed setting `addConversation` as an `action` makes the logs appear in the 'right' order ('Added conversation' then 'Reordering conversation')

Comment: See Tholle's answer, the observed behavior is correct: 1. item is added to collection, 2. computed is called to update because of that. 3. 'added conversation' is logged. Looking at it differently: if you would log the sorted conversations in your first log statement, the correct output would be shown as the computed is updated immediately. (unlike many other frameworks that only update on next tick, leaving you with temporarily stale data)

Answer (score 1):

You are not doing anything wrong. The MobX API looks like regular JavaScript, but every time an observable is updated, all its observers are updated synchronously under the hood. This will not be an issue in this case, but you could wrap the contents of `addConversation` in a [**transaction**](https://mobxjs.github.io/mobx/refguide/transaction.html):

```
addConversation(conversation) {
  transaction(() => {
    this.conversations.push(conversation);
    console.log('Added conversation');
  });
}
```

You could also make the `addConversation` into an [**action**](https://mobxjs.github.io/mobx/refguide/action.html) which also is a `transaction`:

```
@action
addConversation(conversation) {
  this.conversations.push(conversation);
  console.log('Added conversation');
}
```

Comment: As I understand it, a `transaction` is only needed when multiple `observable` mutations are done successively but you only want `observers` (i.e react components) to be notified once. That's not the case here since `conversations` are only mutated once. The `action` recommendation makes sense though.

Comment: @Komo You are right. I was just trying to explain why `Reordering conversations` was logged before `Added conversation`.